# CSS/Bootstrap 3 - Chrome Extension Grid system heading position and background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a chrome extension and I need some help with the design.

I want to make the title like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1af5.jpg

But I ended up with this instead - https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d1AM.jpg

I have no idea how to split a row into 2 parts. Is it possible to make another  row inside a  col-sm-6?

Also, how do you change the background of the chrome extension? Apparently body{} and background-solor: black; doesn't work at all.

Comment: It's difficult to help you while we don't see your code. Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Alexander Oh crap, I don't know how to format my codes in! I have 4 different files; manifest.json, js, html and css file

Comment: It is not necessary to post a wall of code. It isn't helpful. Isolate the issue and provide a code snippet that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Alexander Yup, will keep that in mind. I found the solution already. Turns out it is possible to put <div class="row"> inside a <div class="col-sm-6">. All the while I thought it was not posssible